# How to pass an AsyncTask's result to another Activity?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-thread

How can I get the AsyncTask's result to start another activity with that?
It seems very uncomfortable this AsyncTask...
Now, before onPostExecute finishes, it starts activity without the result.
How can that wait until it finishes without to have to rewrite the whole code?

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements InsertAsyncTask.AsyncInsertTaskCompleteListener {
    private Repository mRepository;
    private String data;
    private int codeId;
    private int editMode = 0;
    private Context mContext;
    private FragmentMainBinding binding;

    
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this.getContext();
        mRepository = new Repository(mContext);

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainfragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        binding = FragmentMainBinding.bind(view);
        
        binding.createFormSaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = binding.codeCreateFormTextInput.getText().toString().trim();
            
            if (!text.equals("")){
                create("save data");
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("code_id", codeId);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private void create(String data){
        if (editMode == 1){
            //updated data to DB
            updateCode(data);
        } else {
            //save data to DB
            save(data);
        }
    }
    
    public void save(String data){
        mRepository.insertTask(data, MainFragment.this);
    }
    
        @Override
    public void onInsertTaskComplete(long[] id) {
        if (id[0] > 0){
            codeId = (int) id[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Repository.java:

```
public void insertTask(String data, InsertAsyncTask.AsyncInsertTaskCompleteListener mListener) {
    new InsertAsyncTask(myDatabase.getCDao(), mListener).execute(data);
}
```

InsertAsyncTask.java:

```
public class InsertAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Long> {
    private static final String TAG = "InsertAsyncTask";
    private cDao mCDao;
    private AsyncInsertTaskCompleteListener callback;

    private long[] insertId;


    public InsertAsyncTask(CDao dao, AsyncInsertTaskCompleteListener cb) {
        mCDao = dao;
        this.callback = cb;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Long aLong) {
        super.onPostExecute(aLong);
        if (callback != null) {
            callback.onInsertTaskComplete(insertId);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Long doInBackground(String... datas) {
        insertId = mCDao.insertCode(datas);
        return null;
    }

    public interface AsyncInsertTaskCompleteListener {
        void onInsertTaskComplete(long[] id);
    }
}
```

Comment: i'd personally suggest finding something else to use, async tasks are a bit dated and (as far as i know) they're actually deprecated

Comment: Yes, I know it unfortunately. What would you suggest to use in Java, I use it with Room, until I fully learn Kotlin. But now I need this to get to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialise value of `codeId` on top as

```
private int codeId = -1;
```

Then inside `onViewCreated` change your condition as:

```
if (codeId != -1){
            create("save data");
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext.getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("code_id", codeId);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Should work fine now.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this create() method is in a button click listener:
binding.createFormSaveButton.setOnClickListener(...
create("save data"); );

that is why it is a problem.

Comment: Don't save it unless your codeId is not set. So, for that initialise codeId = -1 and inside your click listener only save if its not equal to -1.

Comment: Updated, please check.

Comment: Thanks! I needed to refactor the code, but this helped.